# Prove that $T$ is a linear transformation, and prove that for any $A \in V$, we have $T^2(A) = 2T(A)P$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

This is a question my professor gave me for practice. There were some other questions but I have no idea where to even begin with this.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting by the way. Still getting used to the website. :P

Comment: I don't know if you've seen it already, but there are explanations for MathJax on Meta : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You should put your actual question in the body of the question too, not just in the title.

Comment: Oh okay, will get on that immediately!

Comment: Begin by looking at the definition of linear transformations. Just write down what happens when you apply the transformation to $A+B$. The proof is a couple of lines long

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see where A and B are.

Comment: How could you have no idea where to begin? Part (1) is just a straightforward verification of the properties of a linear transformation.

Answer (score 1):

For $A, B \in V$ and $a, b \in \Bbb R$, we have

$T(aA + bB) = (aA + bB)P - P(aA + bB)P = aAP+ bBP - aPA - bPB = a(AP - PA) + b(BP - PB) = aT(A) + bT(B), \tag{1}$

which shows that $T$ is linear.

Next,

$T^2(A) = T(T(A)) = T(A)P - PT(A) = (AP - PA)P - P(AP - PA) = AP^2 - PAP  -  PAP + P^2 A;  \tag{2}$

now we have

$P^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end {bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end {bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = I, \tag{3}$

the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.  Thus,

$T^2(A) = AI - 2PAP + IA= 2A - 2PAP; \tag{4}$

also,

$T(A)P = (AP - PA)P = AP^2 - PAP=  A - PAP; \tag{5}$

comparing (4) and (5), we find

$T^2(A) = 2T(A)P, \tag{6}$

as anticipated.

Comment: How did you arrive at (5)?  Shouldn't $T(A)P $ be equal to $(AP-PA)P$?

Comment: @bloomers:  you know what, I got it backwards! I used $T(A) = PA - AP$.  Will fix.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @bloomers:  OK, think I got it right this time! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  Looks good now!

Comment: @bloomers:  thank you, thank you . . .